# C# SqlConnection caching DNS

Tags: c#, sql-server, dns, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

We're in the process of moving a database to a new data centre. My plan for the migration is to update the DNS record that all clients use when connecting to it.

I've tested this by starting a process that does the following in a loop:

1. Opens a new SQL connection, using a DNS entry as the server name
2. Executes a query using that connection
3. Closes and disposes the SQL connection

While that's running, I update the DNS entry to point to the new server.

The query continues to be executed against the old server unless I stop and restart the process.

I've tried the same when sending web requests using HttpClient and that seems to refresh it's DNS every 2 minutes, but the SqlConnection object hangs on to the original resolution until the whole process is restarted. I assume this is because the connection is pooled, and it doesn't re-validate the DNS entry when it gets the connection from the pool.

Ideally I wanted to avoid having to recycle app pools and restart services as part of the migration. Has anyone else experienced this behaviour? If so, did you find a way to force SqlConnection to re-evaluate the DNS entry it uses as the server name?

Comment: Are you able to redeploy the application before switching database servers? I.e. are code or config changes acceptable?

Comment: There are around 40 individual pieces of software that use this database server in one way or another, so I'd prefer not to, but it's not beyond the realms of possibility.

Comment: As an option - you might have a timer which queries DNS from time to time, and when change is detected - clears all connection pools.

Comment: The first thing to try is : flushing the connection pool  after the DSN change (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx for `SqlClient`) - does that make it work in the expected way?

Comment: @MarcGravell that's already clear from existing answers, but what is the best way to detect that DNS change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With connection pooling, the connection and underlying session will be re-used until the connection is removed from the pool and a new one created. You can force clearing of the connection pool by invoking [SqlConnection.ClearAllPools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx) to clear the pools of the current app domain. You can also turn off connection pooling entirely with the `Pooling=False` connection string keyword but be aware the performance hit may be considerable.